# Filling box-like object with random objects

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm generating training data for a machine learning model using Blender. I want to train an RGB->RGB-D model on images of boxes that are filled with random objects. How would I automatically fill a cube-like area with random meshes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a particle system.

Create a new particle system on the cube, and tweak it's settings so the particles fill the cube (something like : "Emit From : Volume", "Physics : No", "Render/Unborn : checked", "Render/Emitter : unchecked".

Select all your random objects and add them to a group (<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>). Place them on an hidden layer.

In the particle system settings, in Render, select Group, then in Dupli Group select your group.

Comment: Thank you! How do I make sure that the emitted meshes do not intersect with the cube's?